# How to get arrived timestamp of a request in flask

Tags: python, http, flask, timestamp

I have an ordinary Flask application, with just one thread to process requests. There are many requests arriving at the same time. They queue up to wait for be processed. How can I get the waiting time in queue of each request?

```
from flask import Flask, g
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.before_request()
def before_request():
    g.start = time.time()
    g.end = None

@app.teardown_request
def teardown_request(exc):
    g.end = time.time()
    print g.end - g.start

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def serve_run():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that using Flask's debug server in single-threaded mode (which is what your example code uses).  That's because by default, the Flask debug server merely inherits from Python's standard `HTTPServer`, which is single-threaded.  (And the underlying call to `select.select()` does not return a timestamp.)

> I just have one thread to process requests.

OK, but would it suffice to spawn multiple threads, but prevent them from doing "real" work in parallel?  If so, you might try `app.run(..., threaded=True)`, to allow the requests to start immediately (in their own thread).  After the `start` timestamp is recorded, use a `threading.Lock` to force the requests to execute serially.

Another option is to use a different WSGI server (not the Flask debug server).  I suspect there's a way to achieve what you want using GUnicorn, configured with asynchronous workers in a single thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can doing something like this

```
from flask import Flask, current_app, jsonify
import time

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.before_request
def before_request():
    Flask.custom_profiler = {"start": time.time()}


@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    current_app.custom_profiler["end"] = time.time()
    print(current_app.custom_profiler)
    print(f"""execution time: {current_app.custom_profiler["end"] - current_app.custom_profiler["start"]}""")
    return response


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def main():
    return jsonify({
        "message": "Hello world"
    })


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

And testing like this

```
→ curl http://localhost:5000
{"message":"Hello world"}
```

Flask message

```
→ python main.py            
 * Serving Flask app "main" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
{'start': 1622960256.215391, 'end': 1622960256.215549}
execution time: 0.00015807151794433594
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Jun/2021 13:17:36] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```