# get time from client in flask

Tags: python, flask

so i have a flask server and client. i want to send data from client to server, and the timestamp as the part of the message. so this is my code:

```
import os
import requests
import glob
import time 
import base64


url = 'http://0.0.0.0:5000/'
path = './10_mb'
folders = [f for f in glob.glob(path + '**/*', recursive = True)]


send = round(time.time() * 1000)

def load_data():

    for folder in folders:
        with open(folder, 'rb') as imageFile:
            image_s = {'file_image':open(folder, 'rb')}

    return image_s


def send_data():

    r = requests.post(url, files = load_data(), headers = {'ts': str(send)})

if __name__ == "__main__":

    send_data()
```

and this is the server

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
import time 


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])

def home():
    timeout = time.time() + 5  

    while True:
        test = 0
        if test ==5 or time.time() > timeout:
            break

    return 'Hello', 200



app.run(host='0.0.0.0', threaded = True, debug = True)
```

when i run the client, from the server side it doesnt print the timestamp from client. 
my question is, how do i get the timestamp from client? sorry if this is a silly question i'm a total noob. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many attr in [Flask request](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request). Among them, `headers` returns headers of your POST. So adding `print(request.headers)` will work.

```
# in server side...
@app.route("/", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    timeout = time.time() + 5  

    while True:
        test = 0
        if test ==5 or time.time() > timeout:
            break
    print(request.headers)
    return 'Hello', 200


app.run(host='0.0.0.0', threaded = True, debug = True)

# Host: 0.0.0.0:5000
# User-Agent: python-requests/2.22.0
# Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
# Accept: */*
# Connection: keep-alive
# Ts: 1577866093523
# Content-Length: 0
```

Comment: not working for me .. headers is an object of type "EnvironHeaders" and print() on it prints nothing.

Comment: Sadly, this seems not work due to Python or Flask update. Using time.time() [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40402804/how-to-get-arrived-timestamp-of-a-request-in-flask) might help.